# Flask-babel unable to recognize _ or gettext

Tags: python, flask, python-babel, flask-babel

I have the following in my template:

```
<a class="page-scroll" href="#career">{{ _(Career) }}</a>
<a class="page-scroll" href="{{ url_for("comment_new") }}">{{ gettext(Contact) }}</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">{% trans %}Language{% endtrans %}</a>
```

When I run `pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -o messages.pot .`

I am only seeing:

```
#: templates/hello.html:91
msgid "Language"
msgstr ""
```

but not "Career" or "Language". I can't figure out why babel is not interpreting `_` or `gettext` in jinja. Help?

Answer (score 1):

ah turns out I need "" even in jinja. n00b!